# Como alterar o valor das variáveis toda vez que repetir a função def?

Tags: python-3.x

Meu algorítimo soluciona o seguinte problema: **Crie um algorítimo que leia 4 valores digitados e indique se algum par de números soma 8 ou um número maior que 8.**

```
    s = [int(input()) for c in range(4)]
while sum(s) < 8:
    print('Error 01: Erro: A soma de todos os 4 números resulta num número menor que 8, digite outros números.')
    s = [int(input()) for c in range(4)]
    if sum(s) > 8:
        break
x = 0
y = 0
z = 1
s = sum(s[y] + s[z])
while x < 6 or s < 8:
    def funcao(x = 0, y = 0, z = 1):
        if s == 8:
            print(f'Os números {s[y]} e  {s[z]} somados dão 8. ')
        elif s > 8:
            print(f'Os números {s[y]} e  {s[z]} somados resultam num número maior que 8. ')
        else:
            if x == 3 and s < 8:
                funcao(x+1,y+1,z+1)
```

Comment: Qual seria exatamente a dúvida e o que você tem abaixo do comentário "#aqui a função repetiria novamente, só que somando 1 ao valor inicial das variáveis x, y e z."?

Comment: Meu código termina exatamente nesse ponto, porque abaixo disso entraria a função def que começa no primeiro comentário e termina antes do segundo, mas pra isso eu preciso saber como somar 1 no valor das variáveis x, y e z a cada vez que a função se repetir, e assim conseguir testar se existe algum par de número que soma 8.

Comment: Minha dúvida é: Como criar uma função def, de forma que some 1 ao valor das variáveis x, y e z toda vez que a função repetir.

Answer (score 3):

```
 def funcao (x=0, y=0, z=1):

    while x < 3:
        s = sum(s[y] + s[z])
        z += 1
        x += 1
        if s == 8:
            print(f'Os números {s[y]} e  {s[z]} somados dão 8. ')
        elif s > 8:
            print(f'Os números {s[y]} e  {s[z]} somados resultam num número maior que 8. ')
        elif x == 3 and s < 8:
            funcao(x+1,y+1,z+1)
```

Esta meio confuso de entender o que quer pois sinto que o código ta incompleto, afinal nem a def estou vendo.

Ao iniciar a def funcao se você não declarar valores ela vai iniciar em x = 0, y = 0 e z = 1, igual você colocou no inicio da função. E no final dela, ele vai pegar os valores que ja tem do x,y,z e colocar +1 nelas.

Comment: Sim, era isso que eu procurava. Fiz algumas mudanças no código, porém agora o erro ocorre por conta de usar variáveis inteiras para representar a posição da string, tem uma outra forma de fazer isso sem usar inteiros?